# Drawing image in a loop onto canvas - how could I optimize this code?

Tags: javascript, optimization, canvas, drawing

I am drawing a background image on a canvas element. I create a loop with requestAnimationFrame. In this loop, I draw an image onto the canvas with the appropriate coordinates.

The animation seems to be smooth, in Chrome 60 fps, but I have few glitches every now and then. It's worse in Firefox than in Chrome. It's better when I view it with a clean profile, without open tabs - but it's still not perfect.

Here is the full source: http://jsbin.com/vopiw/1/edit?html,output

This function gets called in every frame:

```
function draw(delta) {
    totalSeconds += delta;

    var vx = 100; // the background scrolls with a speed of 100 pixels/sec
    var numImages = Math.ceil(canvas.width / img.width) + 1;
    var xpos = totalSeconds * vx % img.width;

    context.save();
    context.translate(-xpos, 0);
    for (var i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
        context.drawImage(img, i * img.width, 0);
    }
    context.restore();
}
```

Can you spot anything, which could be a real performance drawback?

What I have found so far:

- memory consumption is growing slightly but constantly
- BUT there is no garbage collection happening, which could be blamed for the glitches

Do you maybe have any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the image as a background image on the element itself and use background position to scroll it.

Instead of the `img` `onload` just go directly into the code:

```
(function imageLoaded() {

  canvas.style.backgroundImage = 'url(...)';
  canvas.style.backgroundRepeat = 'repeat-x';
  draw(0);
  ...
```

Then just update the `draw()` method with something like this:

```
// cache these
var iw = 400,
    cw = canvas.width;

function draw(delta) {

    totalSeconds += delta;

    var vx = 100;  // if always 100 just insert the value directly below
    var numImages = ((cw / iw)|0) + 1;  // use logic OR to remove fractions
    var xpos = totalSeconds * vx % iw;

    // update background position
    canvas.style.backgroundPosition = (-xpos + iw) + 'px 0';
}
```

The second issue is the way you calculate the time delta. Using the low-resolution timer can add to the jerky-ness.

Try to use the built-in high-resolution timer instead. Luckily the rAF provides a high-res time stamp which you can use instead:

```
function loop(now) {  // use argument from rAF (hi-res timestamp)
    if (!looping) {
        return;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);

    var deltaSeconds = (now - lastFrameTime) * 0.001; //mul is faster than div
    lastFrameTime = now;
    draw(deltaSeconds);
}
```

**[Modified jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yivarace/2/edit)**

This hands the drawing action to the browser but have in mind that the gain is not all that. The reason is that the `drawImage()` method is pretty fast in itself but you are saving a few steps in the JavaScript which is the real bottle-neck (canvas is very fast in itself despite the myth) and the repetition of these draw operations are left to internal compiled code in the browser.

Other factors that influence the smoothness is the hardware clock and hardware capability in general as well as other things going on in the browser.

I would also put that canvas element on an absolute or fixed position as the browser will give the *element* a separate bitmap (not related to canvas bitmap) for it which could improve the CSS background performance (not shown in the modified jsbin).